# Error with ruby script "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Ruby version 1.9.3( I know this is old and I intend to upgrade). When I run my script I see this error  "The system cannot find the file specified" I had another version of Ruby installed (2.0) which was giving me problems so I uninstalled it and have the old version. Below is the code and error.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
qa= Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
qa.navigate.to "website url"
sleep 3
qa.close
```

- **ERROR**

> ruby AMO.rb
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: FWIW - this URL is invalid: `"https://https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"`.

Comment: @orde I just edited my project's url. I have tried different (accurate) urls and get the same error

Comment: Can you give the full exception (ie the backtrace)?

Comment: given that ruby 1.9.3 is no longer supported and selenium is actively developed, i really doubt using the old version will help. anyway i ran this code and it worked for me when using `http://google.com` as the url. A better way to debug might be to paste the code into IRB one line at a time, to see which one is specifically causing the error.

Comment: @max pleaner what is IRB ? Also if I remove the version 1.9.3 from my system and install a new version will this cause to remove my old scripts created in the old version ?

Comment: @Amrita IRB is "interactive Ruby shell", it is essential for Ruby development. I don't know what system  you are running on but in general no, removing a Ruby version will not delete the scripts. Ruby is just used to run the scripts ... the scripts are still stored as normal files. Rather than removing 1.9.3, I recommend using RBenv to install a current Ruby version (2.3.0).